# kafka streams DSL: add an option parameter to disable repartition when using `map` `selectByKey` `groupBy`

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

According to the documents,  streams will be marked for repartition when applied `map` `selectKey` `groupBy` even though the new key has been partitioned appropriately.  Is it possible to add an option parameter to disable repartition ?

Here is my user case:
there is a topic has been partitioned by `user_id`.

```
# topic 'user', format '%key,%value'
partition-1: 
         user1,{'user_id':'user1', 'device_id':'device1'}
         user1,{'user_id':'user1', 'device_id':'device1'}
         user1,{'user_id':'user1', 'device_id':'device2'}
partition-2: 
         user2,{'user_id':'user2', 'device_id':'device3'}
         user2,{'user_id':'user2', 'device_id':'device4'}
```

I want to count user_id-device_id pairs using DSL as follow:

```
stream
      .groupBy((user_id, value) -> {
                JSONObject event = new JSONObject(value);
                String userId = event.getString('user_id');
                String deviceId = event.getString('device_id');
                return String.format("%s&%s", userId,deviceId);
       })
       .count();
```

Actually the new key has been partitioned indirectly. There is no need to do it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `.groupBy()`, it always causes data re-partitioning. If possible use groupByKey instead, which will re-partition data only if required.

In your case, you are changing the keys anyways, so that will create a re-partition topic.

Comment: In fact, the data has been partitioned indirectly (data is repartitioned by user_id, but  user_id_device_id  also be partitioned too), so repartition is not needed. 

Besides, I do not want to change the key of kafka record,   I just want the key I used for aggregation in kafka streams is  user_id_device_id but not user_id

Comment: GroupByKey/Aggregation won't change the key of the source topic. Instead, it creates a repartition topic as internal topic. That belongs to application.id

Comment: Yes, my suggestion is whether it is possilbe that developer of kafka streams could add an option parameter to disable repartition (because it will generate repartition topics) and the key for aggregation not using the key of record directly but also key generated by value of record

Comment: No, it is not possible at the moment in Streams DSL directly. You can low level Processor API to implement custom logic to avoid the repartitioning

Comment: Thanks,  I will approve the answer,  if there are features about it, please mention it  in later comments.  :)